# Constraints not obeyed in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

So, I have made a photo preview dialog fragment that looks like this:

[image]

The problem is, when I take a landscape photo, suddenly the LinearLayout containing the photo no longer obeys the constraints I had set for it (everything else still is), and it looks like this:

[image]

Note how the arrows are overlapping the photo. Does anyone have advice on how to fix this?

I forgot to add the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/topGuideLine"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="25dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/midGuideLine"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottomGuideLine"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="2dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/rightGuideLine"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/photo_preview_guide_lines"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/rightGuideLine_mini"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="25dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/leftGuideLine"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/photo_preview_guide_lines"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_margin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/leftGuideLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rightGuideLine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bottomGuideLine">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/delete_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxHeight="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/delete"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small_margin"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/retake_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxHeight="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/photo"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/photo_preview_close_button"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/photo_preview_close_button"
        android:src="@drawable/close_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rightGuideLine_mini"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/photo_preview_close_button"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/rightGuideLine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/midGuideLine"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_chevron_right_white_24"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/photo_preview_close_button"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_chevron_left_white_24"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/midGuideLine"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you're trying to use constraints within the linear layouts, and understandably that is not working. Why not get rid of your inner layouts and have a flat constraint layout that includes all the views?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Tried it quick - didn't work. If I remove the linearlayout and play around a bit, the second linearlayout containing the two image views works like I want the photo to work. But, I cannot get the photo to work the same way; whether it is on its own or whether I delete the other stuff and put it in another frame or linear layout. I'm starting to suspect it is the ImageView being difficult.